# jQuery links from HTML

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have the following code in JQuery to create a footer with links:

```
;(function($) { $.fn.piepagina = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var defaults = {images: [
            '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/about.html">About</a> -',
            '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/reportanissue.html">Report an issue</a> -',
        '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/contribute.html">Contribute</a> -',
        '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/contactus.html">Contact Us</a> -',
        '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/termsofuse.html">Terms of Trade</a> - ',
        '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/emailupdates.html">Email updates</a> ']};
        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options || {});           
    });
};})(jQuery);
```

I'm calling the function like follows from my HTML:

```
 <script>$(function() {$('#footer').piepagina();});</script>
```

But I can not see anything on my footer.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks much

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing anything in your code....

Why don't you just try:

```
  this.append( 
    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/about.html">About</a> -',
    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/reportanissue.html">Report an issue</a> -',
    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/contribute.html">Contribute</a> -',
    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/contactus.html">Contact Us</a> -',
    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/termsofuse.html">Terms of Trade</a> - ',
    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/emailupdates.html">Email updates</a> '
  );
```

I *think* that is what you wanted to do... but I cannot be sure....

Not sure why you need a plugin for this....

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to modify your code like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.piepagina = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var defaults = {
                images: [
                    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/about.html">About</a> -',
                    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/reportanissue.html">Report an issue</a> -',
                    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/contribute.html">Contribute</a> -',
                    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/contactus.html">Contact Us</a> -',
                    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/termsofuse.html">Terms of Trade</a> - ',
                    '<a href="http://unlimitedwonders.blogspot.com/2012/12/emailupdates.html">Email updates</a> '
                ]
            };
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options || {});
            for(var i =0; i < settings.images.length; i++) {
                $(this).append(settings.images[i]);
            }
            $(this).data("piepagina", { settings: settings });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

`for` loop after `var settings = ...` line will add all images (links) available in `settings.images` into selected element.

Comment: Why do you need the for loop? It is not needed at all...

Comment: @Neal I'm just not sure how jquery will handle array of strings passed to `.append`

Comment: @Neal Hm. Thanks! Never thought it can handle such input.